# NullPointerException only on tablets

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i have a problem with a NullPointerException.
It occurs only on tablets, it work without problems on smartphones.

I have identified the problem, the button newDemoAccount is null, but i don't know why.
The other button addAcount works without problems.
Both buttons are correct declared in the xml.

```
        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.account_list_footer, null, false);
        addAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.account_footer_btn);
        newAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_account_button);
        newDemoAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_Demo_account);
```

Someone any idea why it don't work only on tablets?

Comment: Do you have a separate tablet layout in your `res` folder where `new_Demo_account` is not declared?

Comment: yes it was a separate tablet layout....
Thanks!